# Processing Files - Keeping Track

Tags: vb.net, file-management

Currently we have an application that picks files out of a folder and processes them. It's simple enough but there are two pretty major issues with it. The processing is simply converting images to a base64 string and putting that into a database.

**Problem**

The problem is after the file has been processed, it won't need processing again and for performance reasons we don't really want it to be so.

Moving the files after processing is also not an option as these image files need to always be available in the same directory for other parts of the system to use.

This program must be written in VB.NET as it is an extension of a product already using this.

**Ideal Solution**

What we are looking for really is a way of keeping track of which files have been processed so we can develop a kind of ignore list when running the application.

Comment: what have you tried? i feel it should be a straightforward issue - you might just need to store the file name somewhere, in a datatabase table or a local file (whatever format that is easy for your system to read) and at run time, check whether the file name already in the list...

Comment: It's only straightforward if you've done it before. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every processed image file `Image0001.ext`, once processed create a second file `Image0001.ext.done`. When looking for files to process, use a filter on the extension type of your images, and as each filename is found check for the existence of a `.done` file.

This approach will get incrementally slower as the number of files increases, but unless you move (or delete) files this is inevitable. On NTFS you should be OK until you get well into the tens of thousands of files.

EDIT: My approach would be to apply KISS:

1. Everything is in one folder, therefore cannot be a big number of images: I don't need to handle hundreds of files per hour every hour of every day (first run might be different).
2. Writing a console application to convert one file (passed on the command line) is each. Left as an exercise.
3. There is no indication of any urgency to the conversion: can schedule to run every 15min (say). Also left as an exercise.
4. Use PowerShell to run the program for all images not already processed:

   ```
   cd $TheImageFolder;
   # .png assumed as image type. Can have multiple filters here for more image types.
   Get-Item -filter *.png |
     Where-Object { -not (Test-File -path ($_.FullName + '.done') } |
     Foreach-Object { ProcessFile $_.FullName; New-Item ($_.FullName + '.done') -ItemType file }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In a table, store the file name, file size, (and file hash if you need to be more sure about the file), for each file processed. Now, when you're taking a new file to process, you can compare it with your table entries (a simple query would do). Using hashes might degrade your performance, but you can be a bit more certain about an already processed file.